# Should I combine YUI's grids with Boilerplate HTML5?

Tags: jquery, html, boilerplate, yui-grids

I'm planning on building a web development template for a small team. I'm looking at combining Paul Irish's Boilerplate and YUI's grids. (If it helps, the group will use jQuery.)

Is there any reason why this would be a bad idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am one of the contributors to HTML5Boilerplate. There is no reason why this would be a bad idea. Boilerplate only gives the scaffold and not any CSS/HTML/JS for grids. So you are totally good to use it.

If there is any insight you have when you combine them, do add it to the [wiki](http://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate/wiki)